# Editing auto generated code by netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

With Netbeans, I have created a GUI form and added a `JList` component. In order to add items, I have create a `ListModel` according to many websites.

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> list = new JList<>( model );
```

Problem is that the second line is automatically generated by Netbeans and it is not editable! So, I see

```
private javax.swing.JList<String> list;
...
list = new javax.swing.JList<>();
```

So how can I change that line to `JList<>( model )`? I have to say that in the generated code, I see

```
 list.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "String" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
```

I don't know how that can be used. I see some questions similar to mine, but it is not clear for me what is exactly the problem and why I can not add/remove items in a normal way as expected!

Comment: you mean you cannot edit it by clicking it?

Comment: Yes I mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because when netbeans generating code for you it will add access modifier `private` for variables and for methods. You can change those to `public`, so then you can change. To do that,

One method:

**Right click** on the jList in the **navigator** or in GUI. Next, go to **customize code** then, you will get pop up window in it chnage **default code** to **custom property**.

Or:

Go to jList **property** -> click on the **code tab** and in it change **variable modifier** `private` to `public` and then you can change code that you shown in the question.

**UPDATE:**

```
model = new DefaultListModel<>();
list = new javax.swing.JList();

list.setModel(model);
```

delete the argument inside the `setModel()` and pass your model into it.

To add element:

```
model.addElement("anything here");
```

One last thing update your `DefaultListModel` declaration to the above of your JForm constructor:

```
DefaultListModel<String> model;
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: @mahmood: take a look at my answer. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: I have updated the post. There is a `setModel` in the generated code and I can see that in proprties->customized code. So, I am not sure what should I do!

Comment: @mahmood inside the `setModel()` pass your `model`

Comment: So, I think that is solved by now but I am not able to properly add elements to it. I will ask in a new question.

Comment: @mahmood change `DefaultListModel<String>  model = new DefaultListModel<>();` to `model = new DefaultListModel<>();`

Comment: then add `DefaultListModel<String> model;` to top of your jform class

Comment: OK.  I understand that. Thanks.